# Do something for every file in a directory and subdirectories

Tags: java, file

I need to apply more complex logic on a list of files. Specifically, when applying software update, I want to do this for files obtained from the update zip archive:

- let `updateFile` be the file from update archive, `originalFile` the current version file and `backupFile` the backup of original file
- if `originalFile` is the same as currently running `jar` file, skip it
- if the `updateFile`'s parent directory is specific name, skip it (eg. directory with user data)

I would prefer to have some options like running a callback for every file:

```
GreatFileLibrary.forEveryChildOf(new File("my path"), 
                                (File child)->{ ... logic here ... });
```

If not this, then at least just get all files in some `Collection` and loop through it:

```
Iterable<File> files = GreatFileLibrary.listChildren(new File("my path"));
for(File child:files) {
    ... logic ...
}
```

The former would allow me to display progress (thanks to knowing list length) but I frankly assume the update will be almost instant.

File of course can return some list of children, so the uber-naive approach is:

```
  /** Returns list of all child files, recursively. **/
  public static Iterable<File> listFileChildren(File parent, ArrayList<File> list) {
    File[] files = parent.listFiles();
    for(File file:files) {
      list.add(file);
      if(file.isDirectory())
        listFileChildren(file, list);
    }
    return list;
  }
  public static Iterable<File> listFileChildren(File parent) {
    return listFileChildren(parent, new ArrayList());
  }
```

Can built-in Java 8 library do that better? Isn't my quick code flawed? I would **really** appreciate to remove converting `File[]` to `Iterable<File>` as my code does, that's dirty.

Comment: I don't know how complex the stuff you want to do on every file is, but this looks like something to do from a shell script, using `find`

Comment: @WalterTross though at this moment I am making Windows only program, I prefer to use cross platform code as much as possible. And the few functions I run from command line (getting UUID for encryption) are actually problematic...

Comment: I see - anyway, Cygwin is your friend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list creation in your code is going to be most time consuming so try and avoid using it.
A simple way of doing this would be:

```
public void forEveryChildOf(File file) {
    for(File child:file.listFiles())
        doForEach(file,child);
}

private void doForEach(File topParent,File child){
    if(child.isFile())
        System.out.println("Do logic");

    if(child.isDirectory())
        for(File subchild:child.listFiles())
            doForEach(topParent,subchild);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind the performance impacts of creating multiple streams, this function will return to you a stream of every child in the target folder.

The version below makes use of `Java 7`'s `Files` and `Path` classes so you may need to rewrite some things (or call `Path#toFile`)

```
public static Stream<Path> stream(Path path)  {
    try {
        return Files.isDirectory(path) ? Files.list(path).map(innerpath -> stream(innerpath)).flatMap(s -> s) : Stream.of(path);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

This version uses plain old `File`s

```
public static Stream<File> stream(File file)  {
    return file.isDirectory() ? Arrays.stream(file.listFiles()).map(innerfile -> stream(innerfile)).flatMap(s -> s) : Stream.of(file);
}
```

You can collect into a `List`, or call `forEach`, on the final `Stream`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void allFiles(File raiz) {          
   for (File arquivo : raiz.listFiles(filtro)) {
      if (arquivo.isFile()) {
          try {              
            System.out.println(arquivo);
          } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("erro" +arquivo);
          }
      } else {
         allFiles(arquivo);
      } 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`FileVisitor` from nio:

```
    Path startPath = new File("...").toPath();
    Files.walkFileTree(startPath, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
        @Override
        public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs)
                throws IOException {
            //your logic

            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }
    });
```